# Is `try: ... except: raise` doing anything in Python?

Tags: python, exception

I saw code like this:

```
try:
    print abc # actually different code was here but it doesn't matter, right?
except:
    raise
```

Was there a reason to put `print abc` in this wierd `try: except: raise` construction? Except clause has only one `raise` operation, so if an Exception was captured, it's only reraised outer, right? So I guess this construction brings nothing except lines of code, am I right?

Answer (score 5):

There is little point in this code. It'll indeed just capture any and all exceptions, then re-raise them again. The traceback and exception are maintained, so the re-raise may as well not be there as far as other Python code is concerned.

It could be that the code once did more than this but the author wanted to minimize the VCS change by keeping indentation the same. Or perhaps thought it'd be a handy point to insert logging or debugging code in case of an exception.

Comment: You're very charitable. Seems just as likely the author just didn't understand what he was doing.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Always a possibility. I'd like to give such a person the benefit of the doubt and have them explain themselves first, but never discount incompetence. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This code is rather useless

```
 except:
     raise
```

Reraises all exceptions, which is exactly the same as not catching them in the first place. It can safely be removed.